# Bloomberg API reference

Tags: vba, bloomberg

I have the following code which works fine with Excel 2010 but due to updated API by Bloomberg this code will not work in Excel 2016. The reference BLP_DATA_CTRLLib.BlpData is outdated but I struggle to use the new API reference.

Does anyone know how do update my Bloomberg reference in order to store the quotes?

```
Function Get_BBG_Price(dataa As Variant, CISI As Long)

    Dim ReqSecurities As Variant, vtResult As Variant, ReqFields As Variant
    Dim Arraystr As String
    Dim oBlp As BLP_DATA_CTRLLib.BlpData

    ReDim ReqSecurities(1 To UBound(dataa, 1))

    For i = 1 To UBound(dataa, 1)

        ReqSecurities(i) = dataa(i, CISI) & "@IEHY ISIN" '  

    Next i

    Set oBlp = New BlpData

   '
   ReqFields = Array("PX_BID")

   With oBlp
       .SubscriptionMode = ByRequest
       .Subscribe ReqSecurities, 1, ReqFields, , , vtResult
   End With

   Get_BBG_Price = vtResult

End Function
```

Comment: Define struggle so we can help you out, are you getting an error message from the code or unexpected results as is?  Can you point to the line of code giving you trouble?

Comment: Please publish some documentation re Bloomberg.  The chances that the SO community has this is very very slim.

Comment: @JimmySmith: It is the BLP_DATA_CTRLLib.BlpData which causes the problem. If I run it on Excel 2016 the worksheet simply crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I was taking a look and it looks like this version of the coding is deprecated.  I would figure you get errors along the line of "cannot create object", but it may be hiding that in 2016.

You'd likely want to use the C# version they have here,
https://www.bloomberglabs.com/api/libraries/

To put it to use, I would use the code here, http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.com/2013/06/bloomberg-v3com-api-wrapper-update-for.html  *The code is too lengthy or I'd post it here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply so far. I would need the code in VBA, so C# is not an option, Please, would you have a suggestion for how I could replace the deprecated reference?

Comment: You cannot directly use the C# version, but the wrapper will allow you to.  You just have to install the Assembly (DLL or EXE) and then make the calls via the wrapper they wrote.

Comment: I did find a C++ version on there, but that requires registering the DLL also.  A lot of .NET is COM compatible, it's just having a wrapper that takes into consideration that variable types changed between VBA and VB.NET/C#

Comment: I have looked at the post by Mikael Katajamäki and have amneded the code as follows. However, I get an 'Invalid procedure call or argument' for the code line 

Set bSecurities = bIteratorData.GetElement("securityData") 

under the function getServerData_reference() in the BBCOM_wrapper. 

Any ideas why? 

ReDim securities(1 To UBound(dataa, 1)) For i = 1 To UBound(dataa, 1) 

securities(i) = dataa(i, CISI) & "@IEHY ISIN" ' IEHY=Iboxx quote 

Next i 

fields = Array("PX_BID") 

data = b.GetData(securities, fields) 

Get_BBG_Price = data 

Set b = Nothing

Comment: Just grasping at straws at moment, but if GetElement is the proper method, then I'm wondering if "securityData" is not an element in your underlying dataset for Bloomberg?

Comment: Finally it works but every tenth security/dataset is empty. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry missed this update.  Is the 10th your last record or you're saying every 10 or so times you get nothing back?  We could be off by 1 somewhere, done that often here.

Comment: Every 10 I get nothing back on my request

Comment: When this happens, does #11 come back with results?  Is this within a shorter time period when you're trying, so say you do it 9 times and wait 5 minutes, does #10 still do that?